# Ajax Search and Pagination Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

this is my controller:

```
public function getIndex()
{

    $val = Input::get('search');
    if (isset($val)) {
        $person = Person::where('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$val%")->orderBy('last_name','ASC')->paginate(15);
        return Response::json($person);
    }

    $allowed = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'father_name');

    $sort   = in_array(Input::get('sort'), $allowed)    ? Input::get('sort')    : 'last_name';
    $order  = Input::get('order')                       ? Input::get('order')   : 'ASC';

    $person = Person::orderBy($sort,$order)->paginate(15);
    $this->layout->content = View::make('hello')->with('person',$person);
}
```

my view

```
... @foreach ($person as $keys => $values)
        <tr class="info">
            <td>{{ $values->first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $values->last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $values->father_name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="search">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="txt">
            {{ Form::open(['url' => 'login']) }}
                {{ Form::text("search","", ["placeholder"=>"جستجو..."]); }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div> ...
```

my ajax

```
$(".search input").on('keyup',function(){
        val = $(this).val();
        if(val.length>2){
            $.ajax({
                url: "dashboard/index",
                type: 'GET',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $(".info").remove();
                    $.each(data.data,function(index,item){
                        $(".menu").append(
                            "<tr class=info>"+
                            "<td>"+item.first_name+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+item.last_name+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+item.father_name+"</td>"+
                            "</tr>"
                        )
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
        }
```

when i search this append into "info" class, but pagination dosen't work
because with this method, search variable is not in url
so when i click to next page it goes to default pagination and not ajax search

please help me

Comment: If you are using pagination then don't use ajax with this, post your search variable to server and reload the page by appending search parameter in the query and the table will be regenerated accordingly and the pagination are also maintained. Otherwise use jquery datatable plugin

Answer (score 0):

when you use table, the best way is using datatable js plugin... you can find the document and examples in site below:
https://datatables.net